# Find pairs of matching values using pandas vectors function

Tags: python, pandas

Given a `df` that looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                    'values' : [2, 4, 6, 8, -8, 10, -4]})
```

and it looks like

```
   id  values
0   1       2
1   2       4
2   3       6
3   4       8
4   5      -8
5   6      10
6   7      -4
```

I want to find pairs of `id`s where the sum of the `values` is `0`. In particular, since `id=4` is `8` and `id=5` is `-8`, then this pair `(4,5)` is identified. Similarly, pair `(2,7)` is also identified.

I believe that the easy way to do this is by using a `for` loop but are there vectorised functions that do so?

Comment: Values are unique? Is possible `0` value?

Answer (score 1):

get series of reversed sign of `df['values']` and use it with `isin`. Next, call `abs` and `groupby` and `agg` on `id`

```
s = df['values'] * -1
df[df['values'].isin(s)].abs().groupby('values').id.agg(tuple)

Out[81]:
values
4    (2, 7)
8    (4, 5)
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If values are unique in column `values`:

```
#filter values pairs with absolute
a = df1.loc[df1['values'].le(0), 'values'].abs()
df = df1[df1['values'].abs().isin(a)].copy()
print (df)
   id  values
1   2       4
3   4       8
4   5      -8
6   7      -4

#convert column to absolute and filter out possible unique rows and aggregate tuples
df['values'] = df['values'].abs()
out = df[df['values'].duplicated(keep=False)].groupby('values')['id'].apply(tuple).tolist()
print (out)
[(2, 7), (4, 5)]
```

Or:

```
#filter nagative
df3 = df1[df1['values'].lt(0)].copy()
df3['values'] = df3['values'].abs()
print (df3)
   id  values
4   5       8
6   7       4

#filter pairs form absolute
df4 = df1[df1['values'].isin(df3['values'])]
#merge together anc convert id columns to tuples
out =  df4.merge(df3, on='values').filter(like='id').apply(tuple, 1).tolist()
print (out)
[(2, 7), (4, 5)]
```